# Unresolved Unit Test Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

Question: When creating Unit Tests, HOW do you instantiate classes from other files?

In my current example: There are two files. The first file contains the class I wish to instantiate, the second is the unitTest.py.

Project.PY has the following

```
class MyNewClass:
  def __init__(self,mystring):
     pass
```

My UnitTest.py attempts to instantiate that class

```
import project
Class MyNewClassTestCase(unit.TestCase):
        def test_something(self):
         MyNewClass("string")
```

As requested here is the direct traceback
Error: 
Traceback
File: 'blahjalalahha', line 6  in test_something
MyNewClass()
Name Error: Global Name MyNewClass is not defined

I am getting a NameError:  MyNewClass is not defined. However, i have used hte IMPORT so I should have that functionality?

Comment: What is giving you the indication that something is not working? Can you provide more details as to what kind of output you are getting that is not what you expect?

Comment: Always include the traceback when asking such questions.

Comment: Name Error:  ... is not defined

Comment: @Vic *Please* be more clear. Edit your question and add the full Traceback. We are not in front of your real code to know what is going on. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your code has a trivial syntax error, so is clearly not a [mcve]. Also, if you `import project`, then the class is accessible as `project.MyNewClass`. Also also, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/.

Comment: Your question is inconsistent - did you call the file `project.py` or `Project.PY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your import is incorrect based on how you are instantiating your class:

Doing this:

```
import project
```

You would have to call your class as:

```
project.MyNewClass("string")
```

So instead do this:

```
from project import MyNewClass
Class MyNewClassTestCase(unit.TestCase):
        def test_something(self):
         MyNewClass("string")
```

It would help you greatly to read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

`MyNewClass` is part of the `project` module which is why you are getting a `NameError` when trying to use it the way you are using it. You either need to reference it from the correct module, `project.MyNewClass` or you need to import the name into your current module, `from project import MyNewClass`

```
import project

class MyNewClassTestCase(unit.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        project.MyNewClass("string")
```